# When is an usb device mounted as sdb and when as sdc?

Tags: ubuntu, automounting

I had a script last week that expected my usb to be sdc, I was using this command

```
usb_path=`lsblk | grep sdc1 | awk '{print $7}'`
```

but then I came back and saw that the stick was empty, because the stick was named sdb. So what does it depend on what name the stick gets? I had no other disk plugged in when it got sdc and no other disk is plugged in now that it is sdb. So the only difference I could see is time, but that seems stupid. Oh and it is the same usb stick as last week.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The letter `b`/`c` in `sdb`/`sdc` is a counter.

The first disk that is detected gets `sda`, the second `sdb`, and so on.

Letters might be skipped if for example you get a temporary loose connection while plugging in your USB stick.
At first the USB stick gets `sdb`, then the connection breaks and is reestablished and it gets `sdc`, because `sdb` wasn't freed yet.

As you cannot count on the same device getting the same name every time,
Ubuntu has a directory with symlinks to disks that are bound to an ID of the filesystem on the disk:
`/dev/disk/by-uuid/`

Every partition on every disk you connect gets an entry in this directory and it always stays the same for the same partition.

If you rather want to access an USB stick that is plugged in into a specific USB port instead of going by the identity of the USB stick, you can use the entries in `/dev/disk/by-path`.

`lsblk` accepts an argument if you want information about a specific device.
So instead of using `lsblk | grep …` you can use e.g. `lsblk /dev/disk/by-id/1234-5678` or `lsblk /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:2.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0`

Comment: Awesome answer, that makes sense. I can't use the uuid, because there will be always different devices. The by-path is exactly what I was looking for. Just wanted to ask how to use it, but I was trying to google first. But I didn't come across a good and simple explanation like yours :)